# Record Not Being Inserted into Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder

We're using the Fire Event endpoint from the REST API (https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/how-to-fire-an-event.html) to insert contacts into a Journey. We are making a request from a Rails application using the Fuel-SDK gem.

We are sending the ContactKey and the attributes for the record in the request. We receive back an eventInstanceId and, sure enough, when we look in the source Data Ext. for the Journey, the record is there. However, it is not inserted into the Entry Event and taken through the Journey.

We've confirmed that the contacts also live on the All Contacts list and in the top 5 of the channel address order. We've tried sending the `EstablishContactKey` attribute as well.

The request does return a 201 Created status, which makes sense given that the record is created in the Data Ext.

Has anyone run into this problem before? What sort of things might cause this behavior to happen? Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: What is error you are getting in the Event Log?

Comment: That's the weird part. We aren't getting any error in the event log. It puts the record in the data extension but does not try to insert it into the Journey. The API call returns a 201 created and an eventInstanceId, indicating to me that things went well.

Comment: Do you have any filters defined which is restricting the injection into the journey ?

Comment: We do have a few filters to protect against null values getting through, but I've verified that the records meet the entrance criteria. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: I have run into similar situations before but every time I have got an error in the log. In your case, it looks like that some entry criteria is not getting met

Comment: If it's not getting inserted into the Journey it means either filter criteria isn't met, or it's having trouble binding the contact. Do a test with a Subscriber record that you KNOW exists in the FIRST item in the channel address order; I've always suspected that the channel address order is a bit sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue when the Data Extension used for the fire event was not part of an Attribute Group linking back to a Population.